# apt-get update / install do not work

Tags: apt, updates, 19.04

Ubuntu 19.04

This has been happening for a little while. Whenever I run apt-get update or install nothing will work.

```
sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://ca.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
  Could not resolve 'ca.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://ca.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease                                                 
  Could not resolve 'ca.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://ca.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease                                               
  Could not resolve 'ca.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                           
Hit:5 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                                                                   
Hit:6 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu disco InRelease                                                         
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu disco InRelease                                      
Hit:8 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://ca.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ca.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ca.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-updates/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ca.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ca.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/disco-backports/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ca.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I've been trying to find the answer but nothing has worked. I'm lead to believe I need to update Ubuntu but whenever I try to update things like with the software center it can't find anything.
When I try to open the software updater it just says it couldn't download repository information.

I'm a-ok to update my distro but I don't know how to. I've got backups so that's not too worrying.

I know ever since I got ubuntu that I've gotten notifications about packages not being found. But I've been trying to setup glfw and packages that are exact hits on ubuntu packages come up as not found.

What needs to be done here? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think old-releases have local country mirror, you can try main mirror instead.

```
sudo sed -i.bak 's/ca.old-/old-/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt update
```

You should upgrade to supported releases, currently it's Ubuntu 19.10, and newest 20.04 LTS.

Comment: This seems to have worked and yep I'm on 20 now. Could you perhaps enlighten me on what happened?

Comment: @DerekC. `apt` failed to contacting `http://ca.old-releases.ubuntu.com`, hence the fail— you too can try entering the site or `ping`-ing it and see it for yourself, the site simply doesn't exist.